# The footer section goes up on a particular page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am a computer science student, in my second year, during my studies, I decided to study on my own, PHP.

I'm trying to build a shopping site, the whole site I built, everything works, there is only one problem. I disassembled the site into parts - part of header, part of footer, main part.

When the user wants to purchase I refer him to a special page - where the order details are displayed, the problem is this - I want the footer to be at the bottom of the page - as it is also in other parts of the page - only on this page - the footer in the middle.

I tried to make `include` into `require`; I tried to give it a position in `css` - it did not work for me. On other pages it works, on one page it does not work properly.

Sorry for the inconvenience, I'm trying to figure out why on one page it's not working properly, Thanks for the help.

```
<?php
include('header.php');
include('arrays.php');


$obj = json_decode($_POST['array_data'], true);
$totalPrice = $_POST['totalPrice'];

echo '
<div class="my-container">
<table class="table table-dark">
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Title</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">picture</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        
        ';
$count = 0;
foreach ($obj as $row) {
    if ($row['amount'] > 0) {
        echo
            '<tr>
            <th scope="row">' . $row['name'] . '</th>
            <td>' . $row['price'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['amount'] . '</td>
            <td><img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src=' . $Items[$count]['picture'] . '></td>     
        </tr>';
    }
    $count++;
}

'<tbody>
</table>
</div>';

include('footer.php');
?>
```

the full code is on github:
https://github.com/avraamya/website-development

[image]

Comment: it looks like you miss a tbody end tag ( typo here ). Can you retry with this dom problem fixed ?

Comment: its very inconvinient to try to help. Its highly advisable to just add proper html and proper css for the sake of simplicity and then relate to the problem. I will guess that your `footer` is sticking on other pages to the bottom because your content is using 100% of the height of the window and on your "special" page only use some part. :) Welcome to StackO !

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just closed the tbody, thanks for the comment. I ran the code one more time, with the fix, but the footer is still in the middle, it's weird - do not understand what I'm missing. What do you think might cause this?

Comment: Thanks for the help, how can I know - does the content on this page not capture 100%, compared to other pages it does capture 100%?

Comment: Your closing tags are wrapped in quotes for some reason. Perhaps you meant to echo that

Comment: Thank you for the help, these were the problems, now it works - I forgot to close the tbody tag - and register echo. Thank you very much for your help. It happens to me a lot that all my mistakes are small problems. Probably a result of recklessness.

Comment: @phpmaster Overlooking stuff is normal, but you would likely run into less issues when it comes to `echo` by not using it for html code blocks unless you really have to. You can instead use this pattern: `?> regular html here <?php // resume the php code`

Answer (score 0):

Try this style for your footer tag. Hope it works.

```
.footer { position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; padding: 1rem; text-align: center; background-color: #B0C4D4;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I added your comment into the style file - the footer stays in the middle - I do not understand why it did not work, could there be another problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;            /* Footer height */
}
```

This will keep the footer at the bottom of the page, I guess.